# Change an attribute from an instance with a tkinter Listbox

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter, listbox, bind

I am new here, and I am a beginner in tkinter. I  want to change the attribute of a specific instance from a class. To select the instance, I want to use a Listbox. Here is simple version of the code for the creation of the Listbox. Is it possible to change the flag attribute of the selected instance (if apple is cliked on, change apple.flag to 1) ?

Thanks!

```
import tkinter as tk

class fruits:
    all_fruits = []
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.flag = 0
        self.name = name
        fruits.all_fruits.append(self.name)

root = tk.Tk()
#Main window
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
#Fruits selection
selectorlist = tk.Listbox(frame)
selectorlist.pack()

#Fruits creation
apple = fruits('apple')
pear = fruits('pear')

#List creation
for item in fruits.all_fruits:
        selectorlist.insert(tk.END, item)

#Effect on click
selectorlist.bind("<Button-1>",lambda *a: print("Flag is 1"))
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

With a few changes it can be done, I tried to add as many comments as I could to help explain why.

```
import tkinter as tk

class fruits:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.flag = 0
        self.name = name

def clicked(e):
    # Function that gets the selected value, then changes the flag property and prints the flag.
    selected = e.widget.get(e.widget.curselection()) # Gets the index of the current selection and retrieves it's value.
    all_fruits[selected].flag = 1
    print(selected, "changed to", all_fruits[selected].flag)

    test() # This is a function call to print the entire dictionary so changes can be seen.

def test():
    # Function to print the all_fruits dictionary.
    for k,v in all_fruits.items():
        print(k, v.flag)
    print()

root = tk.Tk()
#Main window
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
#Fruits selection
selectorlist = tk.Listbox(frame)
selectorlist.pack()

#Fruits creation
names = ['apple', 'pear', 'grape', 'orange', 'pineapple'] # List of fruit names.

all_fruits = {} # Define a dictionary for all fruits.
for name in names:
    # Add each name as a dictionary key with the class as its value.
    all_fruits[name] = fruits(name)

#List creation
for item in all_fruits:
    # Insert each dictionary key into the listbox
    selectorlist.insert(tk.END, item)

#Effect on click
selectorlist.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", clicked) # Changed this to call a function

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

To implement Add/Remove functions it would almost be better to restructure the class so that there is a separate class managing the all of the fruits.

I added some functions for add/remove that could be helpful later:

```
import tkinter as tk

class fruit:
    """A Class for each fruit."""
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.flag = 0
        self.name = name

    def change(self, value):
        self.flag = value

class fruits:
    """A Class for all the fruits."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_fruits = {}

    def add(self, listbox, name):
        self.all_fruits[name] = fruit(name)
        listbox.insert(tk.END, name)
        print("Added", name)

    def remove(self, listbox, name):
        indx = listbox.get(0, tk.END).index(name)
        listbox.delete(indx)
        del self.all_fruits[name]
        print("Deleted", name)

    def change(self, name, value):
        self.all_fruits[name].change(value)

def clicked(e):
    # Function that gets the selected value, then changes the flag property and prints the flag.
    selected = e.widget.get(e.widget.curselection()) # Gets the index of the current selection and retrieves it's value.
    Fruits.change(selected, 1)
    print(selected, "changed to 1")

    test() # This is a function call to print the entire dictionary so changes can be seen.

def test():
    # Function to print the all_fruits dictionary.
    for k,v in Fruits.all_fruits.items():
        print(k, v.flag)
    print()

root = tk.Tk()
#Main window
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
#Fruits selection
selectorlist = tk.Listbox(frame)
selectorlist.pack()

#Fruits creation
names = ['apple', 'pear', 'grape', 'orange', 'pineapple', 'carrot'] # List of fruit names.

Fruits = fruits() # Creates an instance of fruits

for name in names:
    Fruits.add(selectorlist, name) # Add each name with the class's add function.

Fruits.remove(selectorlist, "carrot")

#Effect on click
selectorlist.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", clicked) # Changed this to call a function

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works, but why can't I use the all_fruits list inside the class for the name ? (if I put the all_fruits list inside the class, it works for the list creation, but did not work in the click function. selected returns the name and not the index). Is it possible to create the "dictionary key" within the class ? (Later, I want to add and delete fruits)

Comment: @Dr.TK I added the method I would use, basically adding a class to handle all of the fruits.

Comment: Thank you so much  @tgikal for your answers and your explanations. Now I know how to manage all of my fruits. The creation of a separate class seems to be a nice solution.

Comment: @Dr.TK I did have a typo in the remove function, I added a test for it below the adding loop, it adds, then removes "carrot".